# remove spaces after removing comments from a c file

Tags: c, file-io

I have successfully removed single and multi line comments from input.c file but there are empty lines being created in output.c file wherever the comments were in input.c file. How to remove them?

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
  FILE *f1,*f2;
  char c;
  int i=0;
  f1=fopen("input.c","r");
  f2=fopen("output.c","w");

  while((c=getc(f1))!=EOF)
   {
       if(c=='/')
         {
            if((c=getc(f1))=='*' )
              {
                  do
                    {
                    c=getc(f1);
                    }while(c!='*');

                  c=getc(f1);
                  if(c=='/')
                  c=getc(f1);
              }
            else
             {
                 if(c=='/')
                  {
                       do
                       {
                       c=getc(f1);
                       }while(c!=10);
                  }
             }
         }
     fseek(f2,1,i++);
     putc(c,f2);
   }
fclose(f1);
fclose(f2);
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your code for block comments is flawed. It doesn't work correctly if the block comment contains embedded `*` characters.

Comment: yeah you are right. i know but its just a very basic program to get an idea of how compiler works..

Comment: If you only want an idea of how a compiler works, your program is much too complicated (and working correctly, i.e., eliminating empty lines, is not important at all).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
c=getc(f1);
if(c=='/')
c=getc(f1);
```

here do:

```
if (c=='\n')
  c=getc(f1); /* that will read next char from input, when last red char is '\n' */
```

The last line reads next character after ending '/'. You should put c in output file only if it's not '\n'.

Same here:

```
do
{
c=getc(f1);
}while(c!=10);
```

Here always do:

```
c=getc(f1);
```

to remove '\n' that is must be in c variable to stop loop executing.

This should look like this to actually work.

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
  FILE *f1,*f2;
  char c;
  f1=fopen("fahr.c","r");
  f2=fopen("output.c","w");

  while((c=getc(f1))!=EOF)
   {
       if(c=='/')
         {
            if((c=getc(f1))=='*' )
              {
                  do
                    {
                    c=getc(f1);
                    }while(c!='*');

                  c=getc(f1);
                  if(c=='/')
            c=getc(f1);
          if(c=='\n')
            c=getc(f1);
              }
            else
             {
                 if(c=='/')
                  {
                       do
                       {
                       c=getc(f1);
                       }while(c!=10);
               c=getc(f1);
                  }
             }
         }
     putc(c,f2);
   }
fclose(f1);
fclose(f2);
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your suggestion for one-line comments works. Block comments, however, can start and end anywhere. There may be valid code after a block comment before the next newline character. So you would have to check that there is no valid code on that line before removing the end of line character(s).

Comment: And it will proceed with a valid code if there is any. When it looks like */\n it will remove \n. If there is */correct code it will proceed as it should, not touching new line nor first character after '/'. Can's see where it's wrong.

Comment: zubergu, its working. but now its all coming in one line. i wished if it was same as before except the empty spaces

Comment: @sandy I bet you checked if c is '\n' just before putc(c,f2). And you should do it once after exiting first do..while loop. After second do..while just add another c=getc(f1) to drop '\n' that c variable is holding.

Comment: Klas Lindback  when i write comment in printf statement, it removes it. but otherwise its working fine. i didn't understand block comment

Comment: @zubergu yes i did the same.

Comment: @sandy I made my suggestion more clear in edited comment above.

Comment: @zubergu i tried but its not working. i also tried fseek(f2,1,i++) where i=0, still the same

Comment: @sandy yes, it does. I tried and it's fine, except embedded '*' charactes but that's not what You were asking for.